# Sencha touch overlay effect for Ex.Msg.alert doesnt close

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

After i updated my chrome version from 43 to 44 stable, I have been battling with the Sencha touch overlay-effect for both the Ext.Msg.alert() and the DatePicker components. After clicking the "Done" button, the overlay doesn't disappear and it blocks the UI, How can i solve this is there a CSS class or something. Please check the illustrative images

code for alert box

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Sorry', responseData.ServerMsg);
```

code for datepicker

```
    {
     id: 'myID',
     xtype: 'datepickerfield',
     labelAlign: "top",
     value: new Date(),
     dateFormat: 'd M Y' 
   }
```

[image: Please check below images]

Comment: Return to Chrome v43 ? :D

Comment: Easiest workaround would be `Ext.Msg.setMasked(false)`, but that would solve the symptoms, not the problem.

Comment: @Benoit, can you tell that to 10000+ users, This also happens after the app is packaged to an apk on phonegap

Comment: I know, was just kidding ;)

Comment: Did you try to update to the latest ST version?

Comment: Any errors in the JS console ?

Comment: nothing on the console, i think it might a styling issue

Comment: It's a bug of sencha touch, try putting this in launch function on `app.js`: `Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.showAnimation = false;`

Comment: Sometimes after animation close event does not fire, check this out [link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?284450) .

Answer (score 1):

I updated my Sencha touch version from **touch-2.4.0** to **touch-2.4.2** to solve this. i went to my app folder then run

```
sencha app upgrade [path/to/touch-2.4.2]
```

The command updates the touch folder inside my app folder. I had to rename my app.json to avoid merge conflicts the restored it afterwards. This new version comes with couple of fixes. The above mentioned problem and chrome scrolling issue aswell.